# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method elapsedNow()D in class Lkotlin/time/TimeMark

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I have recently updated the version of `Kotlin` to `1.4.0-rc`.

Since then `Koin` is returning the run time error below:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method elapsedNow()D in class Lkotlin/time/TimeMark`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With the latest **alpha version** the problem is solved in my case.

```
// latest unstable
koin_version = '2.2.0-alpha-1'
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-fragment:$koin_version"
```

Go to the main documentation for more details: [Koin latest version](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin#maven-central---latest-version-)

Another way to avoid the problem is how @Aydinozkan says by setting the logger level to error or none.

```
startKoin {
        androidLogger(Level.NONE)          
    }
```

Comment: Apt! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Level.ERROR worked too in a separate library issue!

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 48):

Apparently this issue is due to the usage of `androidLogger()` together with Koin.
There is only a workaround for now, which is migrating from `androidLogger()` to `androidLogger(Level.ERROR)`

There is already an issue created for this purpose:

https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/847

Comment: As mentioned by Martin Bove in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63734210/1139514), the issue has been fixed in Koin version `2.2.0-alpha-1`.

Comment: I had this issue with Koin 2.2.2, but it got fixed in 2.2.3 (which is in a final state, not alpha nor beta). Beware that Koin changed its vendor name from ```org.koin``` to ```io.insert-koin```.

Comment: Same here using 2.2.2 and had to upgrade to 2.2.3 for app to not crash on this